# Using ODBC Driver in Azure to connect to external database

Tags: azure, odbc, driver

I am working in a business in New Zealand. We currently use a remote server (Plexus) to store a large amount of data (some tables > 2 billion rows). We have started down the SharePoint route, and I have created a number of databases and apps in SharePoint that use this data. Currently, I have to run a program in New Zealand that downloads the data to our local server and then pushes up that data into an Azure database, which the web apps connect to. I would like to remove this middle step for many reasons but the biggest reason is that the web connection between NZ and the US tends to result in a lot of time outs and long pulls due to having to pull large data sets across the Pacific. The remote database we are using is Plexus.

Ideally, I would like to have my C# code sitting in Azure and have this connect to the remote server directly. This way I could simply send the SQL request to Plex and have this data go directly into the Azure databases. The major advantage would be that this would mean it would all be based in the US which would make things a lot faster.

The major hurdle is that we need to install an ODBC Driver given to us by the remote server into Azure so it recognises the calls as genuine. Our systems adminstrator has said he has looked into it and it seems this can't be done?

I was hoping someone on the StackOverFlow community has encountered a similar issue and resolved it?

Note: Please dont think I am asking whether Azure has an ODBC connection because I know it does. *I am not asking if I can connect TO Azure*, *I am asking if I can connect Azure to another external data source*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a virtual machine in the same Azure data center as your database and install your ODBC driver and your C# app.

Comment: I havn't done this before so do you know of any tutorials or sites that outline the process?

Comment: Tutorials are off-topic on StackOverflow but the online documentation on Azure.com has plenty of steps-by-steps examples. Once created look for info on how to RDP (Remote Desktop) to your VM.  You'll be able to connect to your VM, download and install the ODBC driver from the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

In a Worker Role/Cloud service in azure you can install the ODBC driver in a startup task using powershells ODBC commandlets.

More info here: [Powershell Add-OdbcDsn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771022(v=wps.630).aspx) and here: [Powershell startup task in cloud services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/#create-a-powershell-startup-task)